What's the logic behind Ashley's bathroom behavior in the Compound V theft scene?
In The Boys (Season 4, Episode 4), I am pretty confused by what happened between Ashley Barrett and A-Train during a scene where A-Train steals Compound V from Homelander's private residence.
What the scene is all about:

A-Train steals Compound V from the Homelander's private residence, and Ashley Barrett shows up there too and witnesses A-Train's theft.
A-Train quickly travels to an unknown place and back and threatens Ashley with "you left a floater," by which I assume Ashley does not flush the toilet after she uses it.
Then both A-Train and Ashley agree they have something that may get each other killed if Homelander learns about them, and both agree to keep it a secret.

What confuses me is:

We know A-Train sneaks into the private residence to steal Compound V, but Ashley sneaks into the private residence to use its toilet, and as an adult, surprisingly, she does not flush it after using it?

What is the logic here, and is there anything I am missing?

Ashley's actions in this scene can be better understood in the context of the previous episode. In the previous episode (ep. 3), Homelander humiliated Ashley by dismissing her from a meeting of The Seven, agreeing with Sage that Ashley was "just a mascot." This was particularly hurtful to Ashley, who prides herself on her constant presence and dedication (to Vought and Homelander).
Later, while venting her frustrations to Cameron Coleman (the news anchor), Ashley expressed her anger and disappointment at being treated this way. In response, Coleman suggested she "leave a floater in [Homelander's] toilet" as a petty act of revenge. It seems Ashley took this advice to heart.
This behavior, while immature and petty, is not out of character for the world of The Boys, where characters often resort to childish or extreme actions. Ashley's decision to sneak into Homelander's residence just to leave an unflushed toilet was her way of secretly lashing out at him for the recent humiliation.
So, to clarify the logic, Ashley didn't go there primarily to use the toilet; she went there specifically to leave it unflushed as a small act of defiance against Homelander. This coincidentally occurred at the same time as A-Train's theft of Compound V, leading to their mutual agreement to keep each other's secrets.
